# dc.js geoChoroplethChart doesn't display legend

Tags: d3.js, dc.js

I'm trying to plot a dc choropleth , but somehow the legend is not showing up. 
Here is the sample fiddle : 
http://jsfiddle.net/susram/9VJHe/56/

```
        usChart
        .width(1200)
        .height(500)
        .dimension(state_dim)
        .group(latest_mean_sqft_per_state)
        //.colors(d3.scale.quantize().range(["#E2F2FF", "#C4E4FF", "#9ED2FF", "#81C5FF", "#6BBAFF", "#51AEFF", "#36A2FF", "#1E96FF", "#0089FF", "#0061B5"]))
        .colors(d3.scale.quantize().range(["#fff7fb","#ece2f0","#d0d1e6","#a6bddb","#67a9cf","#3690c0","#02818a","#016c59","#014636"]))
        //.colors(d3.scale.quantize().range(d3.schemeBlues()(9)))
        .colorDomain([0, 500])
        //.colorAccessor(function (d) { /*console.log(d);*/ return d? usChart.colors(d.avg_psft) : '#ccc'; })
        .colorAccessor(function (d) { /*console.log(d);*/ return d.avg_psft; })
        .overlayGeoJson(statesJson.features, "state", function (d) {
            return d.properties.name;
        })
        .valueAccessor(function(kv) {
            console.log(kv);
            return kv.value;
        })
        .title(function (d) {
            return "State: " + d.key + "\nAverage Price per SqFt: " + numberFormat(d.value.avg_psft ? d.value.avg_psft : 0) + "M";
        })
        .legend(dc.legend().x(1300).y(80).itemHeight(13).gap(5));
```

Why is the legend showing up as 0x0 ? 
[image: legend showing up as 0x0]

Answer (score 3):

I've been trying to get the legend to work with geoChoroplethCharts as well and unfortunately legend support appears to not have been implemented yet in dc. There are a few functions (legendables, legendHighlight, legendReset, legendToggle, ect...) that were defined in the dc base-mixin and would need to be extended before legend support would work.

For an example take a look at the source for pieChart:

https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/develop/src/pie-chart.js

Versus the soruce for geoChoroplethChart:

https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/develop/src/geo-choropleth-chart.js

You'll notice at the bottom of the pieChart source that the related legend functions were extended. I belive something similar would need to be done for the geoChoroplethChart source code.

EDIT:

I worked off your jsfiddle and was able to get a bare bones label to display on the geoChoroplethChart: http://jsfiddle.net/Lx3x929v/2/

```
usChart.legendables = function () {
    return usChart.group().all().map(function (d, i) {
        var legendable = {name: d.key, data: d.value, others: d.others, 
        chart: usChart};
        legendable.color = usChart.colorCalculator()(d.value);
        return legendable;
    });
};
```

[image]

Comment: usChart.group().all() would give us "State as key, State's value as value"  pairs . And so we will end up with  a legend item for every state. But rather , legend , in this case, should say what values dark blue is trying to show and what values light blue is trying to show.  
To achieve this functionality , may be we should try usChart.group().reduce(logic_to_group_colors )  to get colors as keys. But what if the filtered data doesn't have values for a color ?

Comment: To map the values value of the colors to a legend we can instead of using usChart.group().all() we can use the color range. See this updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pv2xk4tm/1/

Answer (score 0):

Here is my modification —for a continuous map— from @MarcTifrea 's solution and comment.

```
    chart.legendables = function () {
        var domain = chart.colorDomain();
        return domain.map(function (d, i) {
            var legendable = {name: parseFloat((Math.round(domain[i] * 100000) /100000).toPrecision(2)) , chart: chart};
            if (i==1) legendable.name += ' unit'; // add the unit only in second(last) legend item
            legendable.color = chart.colorCalculator()(domain[i]);
            return legendable;
        });
    };

    chart.legend(
        dc.legend()
            .x(width/4)
            .y(height*4/5)
            .itemHeight(height/30)
            // .itemWidth(width/25)
            .gap(5)
            // .horizontal(1)
            // .autoItemWidth(1)
    );
```